# Is there a word for something which loses meaning or value when described?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes a concept which loses its power when put into words?

EDIT: For example, the context could be a philosophical (or pseudo-philosophical) idea like "zen" attitude. When a monk can not tell his pupil directly how to achieve enlightenment because the idea is _____.

Comment: What's the context you'd like to use this in?

Comment: The unspeakable or the ineffable ?

Comment: *indescribable?*

Comment: quantum mechanics?

Comment: *wordlessness*.

Comment: *Ephemeral*? *Bullshit*?

Comment: Without context, "Voldemort" would fit.

Comment: The context could, for example, be a philosophical (or pseudo-philosophical) idea like that zen. When a monk can not tell his pupil directly how to achieve enlightenment because the idea is _____.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: **"Meditation is not what you think."** https://yogainternational.com/article/view/meditation-is-not-what-you-think

The word for this, which Graffito suggested yesterday, is **"ineffable."** It is quite profound once you settle into it.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ineffable

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a form of the *[observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics))*

> In science, the term observer effect refers to changes that the act of observation will make on a phenomenon being observed. This is often the result of instruments that, by necessity, alter the state of what they measure in some manner. A commonplace example is checking the pressure in an automobile tire; this is difficult to do without letting out some of the air, thus changing the pressure.

*Wikipedia*